# Is there an easy way to merge Localizable.strings files?

Tags: iphone, localization, internationalization, genstrings

Problem: Using genstrings to create Localizable.strings files from a project. A few weeks later, some things changed and I run genstrings again. 75% of the new file is already in the old file. How could I merge the new file with the old file, so that the old file contains all of those 25% new key-value-pairs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the [Localization Suite](http://www.loc-suite.org/). Incredible powerful tool for free. I tried it on my project and it just works. Lacks documentation though.

Comment: I couldn't get this application to run on either Lion or SL. Is there some guide that I can follow? Are you still using this app?  @MartinWickman

Answer (score 9):

I recommend [Localizable Strings Merge](http://www.delitestudio.com/our-apps/localizable-strings-merge/) too. I use it on my projects and it really a simple to use and powerful software.

Comment: For my latest project I switched to [Linguan](http://www.cocoanetics.com/apps/linguan/) to manage several languages.

Comment: As the future of [Linguan](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/12/linguan-acquisition-update/) is uncertained I took my pilgrim's stick and start to seek for others tool.

This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806682/ios-localization-updating-localizable-strings-with-just-new-strings) list few tools. [Traducto Pro](http://www.traductoapp.com) has catch my eyes and videos on website gave me a very good feeling on it.

Comment: The URL changed: https://products.delitestudio.com/app/localizable-strings-merge/

Answer (score 1):

I use [a script](https://gist.github.com/yoichitgy/29bdd71c3556c2055cc0) to run genstrings with existing translations merged automatically when I build a project. Updated strings are detected by git or another source control you use. The script supports storyboard and xib localization too.

To run the script automatically, put the script into your project root directory, and add a **Run Script** phase with the following line to a target build phases in your project settings.

```
./mergegenstrings.py PathToSourceDir
```

My script is based on the script in [this post](http://www.stevestreeting.com/2010/05/18/os-x-localisation-incremental-genstrings-and-utf-8-files/). I modified it to support Swift and to add the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What about 3rd party applications like BBEdit? After all Localizable.strings file is a text file. BBEdit has a find differences feature and you can merge from old to new or opposite.

Answer (score 0):

If you install XCode, there is also a standard application installed to merge files called FileMerge.app, you can find it in /Developer/Applications/FileMerge.app

Comment: Tried this, it is quite useless as it does just text diff, not considering localization file specifics.

Comment: I think is useful, you can choose left or right diff and do the merge

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure but **ReSharper** may help you. teake a look at it.