# filter with grep to print when text is NOT present in another file

Tags: linux, perl, filter, grep

I have a linux filter to extract all lines from an xcode project that contain localized strings and produce a sorted list of unique entries. The filter works fine and is shown below.

```
grep NSLocalized *.m | perl -pe 's/.*NSLocalizedString\((.+?)\,.*/$1/' | sort | uniq
```

The result is a list of strings looking like this

```
@"string1"
@"string2"
etc
```

What I now need to do is identify the entries that do not exist within another textfile. So imagine I have a text file containing;

```
@"string1"
@"string3"
etc
```

The result would be `@"string2"` as it is not present in the file

For the sake of argument, the file is named list.txt

What do I need to add to my filter? I'm sure I can do this with grep but my brain has failed!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688945/is-there-a-tool-to-diff-merge-sort-localizable-strings-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
grep NSLocalized *.m | 
perl -pe 's/.NSLocalizedString((.+?)\,./$1/' | 
grep -v -f list.txt | #ONLY ADDITION
sort |
uniq
```

You pipe the output of `perl` to `grep` which is using `-v` option to invert the search and `-f` option to get the search pattern from file

Comment: Thanks! That's helped me with another issue - I have realised I have asked the wrong question, I'm going to create a new one as what I actually need is different - apologies!

Answer (score 8):

a Simple GREP switch (-v) prints the inverse. So the command would be

GREP -v -f filename1 filename2 > filename3

Answer (score 2):

You could use [comm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_comm.htm):

```
... your pipeline | comm -23 - list.txt
```

Also - you can probably omit the `uniq` and use `sort -u` if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth making a script out of this (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %existing;

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    $existing{ $_ } = 1;
}

my %nonexisting;

while ( defined( my $file = glob '*.m') ) {
    open my $h, '<', $file
        or die "Cannot open '$file': $!";
    while ( my $line = <$h> ) {
        if ( my ($string) = $line =~ /NSLocalizedString\((.+?),/ ) {
            $existing{ $string } or $nonexisting{ $string } = 1;
        }
    }
}

print join("\n", sort keys %nonexisting), "\n";
```

Invoke it using:

```
$ find_missing list.txt
```

Comment: Didn't want to write a script to do it - I could do that easily enough but wanted to see how to do it without that.